# Issues with MySQL 5.7 user-created temp tables

Tags: mysql, linux, java

i have a CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE query that creates  a temp table in a particular database  and  multiple sub-select queries will use that same temp table.On MySQL 5.6, all the sub-select queries will execute successfully but now on MySQL 5.7,  I am having some problems where some of the sub-select queries will execute successfully  and then  some will fail with an error 'table doesn't exist'?..Any help please..

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could show us the create table and a query that fails?